# How to plot every single row in a Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I would like to have a 3 x n matrix with plots for a Dataframe

The DataFrame looks like the following:

```
                      file_sizes
A [36556.0, 204052.0, 18029.0, 36866.0, 10310.0]
B [36516.0, 221952.0, 78029.0, 36166.0, 20310.0]
C [26456.0, 284152.0, 38029.0, 36766.0, 50310.0]
D [16356.0, 264452.0, 58029.0, 36166.0, 70310.0]
E [96256.0, 244352.0, 88029.0, 36166.0, 90310.0]
```

I have tried the following but it does not seem to work:

```
for row in df_final['file_sizes']:
    sns.distplot(row)
```

Is there a way to plot the rows using an NxM matrix for the plots?

Comment: can you provide an example of a desired output? What do you mean by plot each row as an NxM matrix?

Comment: What kind of plot are you thinking of? Can you link an example of a similar result?

Comment: I was thinking distplot. NxM means N columns x M rows of plots.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(0,df_final.shape[0]): 
     print(df_final.loc[[i]])
```

or u might prefer

```
print(df.loc[:,:])
```

If it doesn't work, please answer me back!